# "new" brand gTLD and browser security

Tags: browser, cross-domain

any hint on browser security behavior and new gTLDs ?

I mean, for a brand gTLD, is it possible to set a cookie for *.brand, to allow Ajax requests on *.brand, ...?

Best regards